# What is this shrub with long pointed leaves?

Tags: identification

I bought this shrub at Aldi back in the spring. It was just a rootball with a small branch. The label said it was a blueberry, but now that it has leaves, it doesn't look like a blueberry plant. What kind of plant is it?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Brenn's ID is the correct one - its definitely one of the Persicarias/Polygonums, and not Loosestrife.

Comment: And I agree, good job Brenn!!  Someone else had an ID that was Polygonum and I thought, hummm.  Not afraid to make mistakes!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry to chime in with a bit of bad news but this is Smartweed, (Persicaria aka Polygunum)... a weed. It could be [Persicaria lapathifolia](https://www.google.ca/search?q=polygonum%20pensylvanicum&safe=off&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwig-diIuIzPAhVDdj4KHU50B7YQ_AUICCgB&biw=1920&bih=921#safe=off&tbm=isch&q=Persicaria%20lapathifolia), [Polygonum pensylvanicum](https://www.google.ca/search?q=polygonum%20pensylvanicum&safe=off&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwig-diIuIzPAhVDdj4KHU50B7YQ_AUICCgB&biw=1920&bih=921) or one of many other similar species. Too hard to tell from the included images.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Yeah this looks a lot closer, though healthier. I went ahead and pulled it and put it in the compost pile.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like Goose[Gooseneck Loosestrife](https://www.google.com/search?q=gooseneck%20loosestrife&rlz=1C1QJDB_en&espv=2&biw=1455&bih=665&tbm=isch&imgil=WtD4qZeHIRwV4M%253A%253BW4RhLPKWObvwhM%253Bhttp%25253A%25252F%25252Fwww.todayshomeowner.com%25252Fgooseneck-loosestrife-in-the-garden%25252F&source=iu&pf=m&fir=WtD4qZeHIRwV4M%253A%252CW4RhLPKWObvwhM%252C_&usg=__i7dm33oXqxkDJw59qKbIe_u9o-E%3D&ved=0ahUKEwij5sKC1IXPAhVQ-GMKHbn7Av8QyjcIJw&ei=XW_UV-PDL9DwjwO594v4Dw#imgrc=9RpErvKIZpwkoM%3A)Neck Loosestrife.  This is an incredible plant, beautiful high groundcover (1-2').  I love this plant if indeed this plant is Lysimachia clethroides.  Poor thing.  I would dig this up this late fall and transplant to a pot with potting soil or another place in your yard with a bit more shade.  One of my all time favorite plants!  Needs a little fertilizer (lower N than P and K), I'd cut off those stems down to a foot or right above a healthy set of leaves.

Comment: It definitely looks like the pictures, thanks!

Comment: Sorry, bg!!  I do make mistakes but I also know that when I do someone else on this site will definitely check it out to make sure.  Grins!!